# Yii2 - rename file on upload if the file with the same name exist

Tags: yii, yii2

How can I rename file if the file with the same name exist (prevent overwrite)? This method is used for uploading file:

```
// Upload user avatar
    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()):

            $this->avatar->saveAs('../web/images/avatars/' . $this->avatar->baseName . '.' . $this->avatar->extension);
            return true;

        endif;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Tip: don't check for file name. Just uniquely rename every file on upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if file exists with php function and then assign a proper name to your file:

```
$cnt = 1;
while (file_exists(string $filename)) {
    $filename =  $this->avatar->basename . $cnt; 
    $cnt++;
}
```

Then save.